# c:set for bean properties

Tags: jsf, properties, jstl, managed-bean

I'm looking for some piece of code for setting a property in a JSF managed bean. My first idea was something like that:

```
<c:set var="#{loginBean.device}" value="mobil"></c:set>
```

That means I want to set the attribute `device` to the value `"mobil"` without a button have to been clicked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use c:set for this purpose.

```
<c:set value="mobil" target="#{loginBean}" property="device" />
```

Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html

However, setting a static value rarely makes sense. You might consider to set a default value directly in your managed bean class. Also in terms of maintainability since you can handle constants better in the Java code than in the view layer.

Comment: Thank you SOO much - i couldn't figure it out :)

Comment: Just as a side note: JSF 2.2 comes up with a nice solution: View  Actions (see http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#758). 
I prefer to not use jstl if possible. The suggested approach may lead to ugly side effects when a value expression is used instead of a static value, due to the fact that JSTL is evaluated at a different point in time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the JSF tag child tag setPropertyActionListener.  You can set this as a child tag in any ActionComponent.

```
<h:anyActionComponent id="component1">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{loginBean.device}" value="mobil" />
</h:anyActionComponent>
```

**UPDATE:**

I originally misunderstood the users problem.  They have a page, and they want a property to be set when the page loads.  There is a couple ways to do this, but both are a little different.  If you want to set a property to a value after every postback then you can use the @PostConstruct annotation on a ManagedBean method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void initializeStuff() {
  this.device = "mobil";
}
```

Now if I have a ViewScoped or SessionScope bean that needs to be initialized with a default value just once when the page loads then you can set a phase lifecycle event that will run after every postback and check to see if the page should be initialized or not.

**mah.xhmtl:**

```
<f:event listener="#{loginBean.initialize()}" type="preRenderView" />
```

**LoginBean:**

```
public void initialize() {
  if (this.device == null)
    this.device = "mobil";
}
```

Comment: Okey but when i don't want to klick a button (which is a UIComponent) or something only when the webpage loaded?

Comment: @user1581725 So you mean that you only want the device property to be set with this value when the page loads?

Comment: thats all yes - but i really have no idea how to make that - sry i'm really new to JSF..

Comment: Note that you can add setPropertyActionListeners only to action components, not anywhere (as mentioned in the answer).

Comment: @Ingo Thank you... you are correct, it has to be a UIComponent that can have an ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to Comment: If you need the value to be ready on page on load, you could use Managed Bean to directly initialize value or use its constructor or @PostConstruct to do the same.

```
     @ManagedBean
     @ResquestScoped
     public class LoginBean {
          private String device = "some value";
          //Using Constructor
          public LoginBean() {
               device = getvalueFromSomewhere();
          }

          //Using PostConstruct
          @PostConstruct
          public void init() {
               device = getvalueFromSomewhere();
          }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value in the xhtml file you can set via another ManagedBean.  For instance if you have managedBean1 which manages page1.xhtml and managedBean2 which manages page2.xhtml.  If page1.xhtml includes page2.xhtml like:

```
<ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
```

in managedBean1 you can have at the top

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{managedBean2}")
private ManagedBean2 managedBean2;
```

and in the PostConstruct

```
@PostConstruct
public void construct() {
    managedBean2.setProperty(...);
}
```

worked for me anyway...